# Edit functionality using javascript and local storage

Tags: javascript, html

Below is my code for dynamic generation of rows:

```
function addRow() {

        var myName = document.getElementById("name");
        var type = document.getElementById("type");


        var table = document.getElementById("myTableData");

        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);


        row.insertCell(0).innerHTML=myName.value; 
        row.insertCell(1).innerHTML=type.value; 

        row.insertCell(2).innerHTML= '<input type="button" value = "Delete" onClick="Javascript:deleteRow(this)">';
        row.insertCell(3).innerHTML=  '  <a href="#login_form" id="login_pop" onclick="Edit();">Edit</a>';


    }
```

and below is my code for popup after clicking on edit link:

```
<a href="#x" class="overlay" id="login_form"></a>
        <div class="popup">

            <p>Please edit your details here</p>

            <div>
                <label for="firstname" id="attr_Name">Attribute Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="firstname" value="" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="lastname" id="attr_Type">Attribute Type</label>

                <select  id="type1" ><option >Text</option><option >Paragraph</option><option >Dropdown</option></select>
            </div>
            <input type="button" id="button1" value="Save" onclick="saveEditedValues()"/>


            <a class="close" href="#close"></a>
        </div>
```

Now I am using local storage to save my edited values but I am not getting how to reflect it in the dynamically generated rows. Below is code for Local storage:

```
function saveEditedValues(){
        var myName = document.getElementById("firstname").value;
         alert(myName);
        var type = document.getElementById("type1").value;
        alert(type);
    localStorage.setItem("attributeName",myName.value);
    localStorage.setItem("attributeType",type.value);
    var namevar1=localStorage.getItem("attributeName");
    var namevar2=localStorage.getItem("attributeType");


    }
```

Please provide some help

Comment: Do the alert() calls provide the correct values?

Comment: @til_b: Yes it is providing correct values only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to update the table, the save function will need to be able to locate the correct row, which means you will have to pass it something like the row number.

When adding the row, define the onclick event handler of the `Edit` link to pass rowCount

```
 row.insertCell(3).innerHTML=  '  <a href="#login_form" id="login_pop" onclick="Edit(' + rowCount +');">Edit</a>';
```

Add a hidden input to your popup div

```
<input type="hidden" id="editingRow" />
```

and have the `Edit` function populate that value:

```
function Edit(rowNum) {
  ...
      document.getElementById("editingRow").value = rowNum;
  ...
}
```

Then the `saveEditedValues` function can locate the row in the table and update the values

```
function saveEditedValues(){
  ...
      var rowNum = document.getElementById("editingRow").value;
      var row = document.getElementById("myTableData").rows[rowNum];
      row.cells[0].innerHTML = myName;
      row.cells[1].innerHTML = type;
  ...
}
```

like so: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XWDZ9/)

Comment: :Thanx a lot for your help it really worked for me its the same functionality which i want............

Answer (score 0):

```
var myName = document.getElementById("firstname").value;
alert(myName);
var type = document.getElementById("type1").value;
alert(type);
```

`myName` and `type` are the correct values (strings). So

```
localStorage.setItem("attributeName",myName.value);
localStorage.setItem("attributeType",type.value);
```

is wrong, you have to use the plain variables like this:

```
localStorage.setItem("attributeName",myName);
localStorage.setItem("attributeType",type);
```

Comment: But how can I reflect these changes in dynamically generated rows , Will append property work?