# save to localstorage dynamic JQuery rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I think I have a major fault in my webpage design. I need to save the content if I reboot the computer or close the webpage.

I do not have access to any type of a database server only MS Access. I was thinking of utilizing localstorage as the page will be constantly viewed from the same computer.

I found this example [link][Edit functionality using javascript and local storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18073071/edit-functionality-using-javascript-and-local-storage) however I am not sure if it will work.

Can someone look at my example and let me know if I can do this or if I need to abandon this and start over.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var id = 0;

    // Add button functionality
    $("table.dynatable button.add").click(function () {
        id++;
        var master = $(this).parents("table.dynatable");

        // Get a new row based on the prototype row
        var prot = master.find(".prototype").clone(true);
        prot.attr("class", "")
        prot.find(".id").attr("value", id);

        master.find("tbody").append(prot);
    });

    // Remove button functionality
    $(document).on("click", "table.dynatable button.remove", function () {
        $(this).parents("tr").remove();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/deaconf19/csL68/

Thanks

Comment: This code does not seem to have anything to do with saving any data at all, just adding and removing table rows. Where is your data handling?

Comment: Are you running a web server locally?

Comment: I am using SharePoint for the hosting. There is nothing being saved right now but I need to save the data that will be entered into the fields. Also I do not have access to the SQL server or Central admin

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the web page from a web-server -- that is, your URL begins with `http://` or `https://`, then yes, you can use localStorage to save data.

If you are running the file directly from your hard drive, that is, your url begins with `file:`, then you'll have trouble.  Chrome won't let you use localStorage -- I don't remember if Firefox does.

(If you need to run this from your local hard drive and not a server, *and* you are running under Windows, you can turn the file into an `HTA` and save data to a regular file.)